# Exception in mvc.net controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In mvc .net c# i have over loaded OnException action in my base controller

In controller action I have generated zip file using Ionic.Zip.dll

The code for this is like

```
foreach (var file in filesToarchive)
{
    zip.AddFile(@file.FilePath);
}

zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
var rept = reports.First();
return File(Response.OutputStream, "plain/zip", "abc.zip");
```

While downloading the file it throws exception in OnException action in base controller

the exception is :

> System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult.WriteFile(HttpResponseBase
>   response)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.FileResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult
>   actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.b__11()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.<>c__DisplayClass16.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__13()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)

If anybody has any solution then please give it to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a memory stream instead of writing to the response:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    zip.Save(stream);
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "plain/zip", "abc.zip");
}
```

Also I've removed the `var rept = reports.First();` line as I don't see any relevance to the code snippet you've posted.

Comment: Thanks Darin it fulfilled my requirement and worked well

But i just want to know the reason of exception that i had mentioned

Can you please make clear it?

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with the `Ionic.Zip.dll` library but I suppose that when you call `zip.Save(Response.OutputStream)` it flushes and closes the stream, and later when you return the file result out of this stream as it is closed it cannot be read. The `File` extension method which takes a stream tries to read this stream and write it to the response stream.

Comment: Drain you are right but after throwing exception it was opening download window with containing zip file and i could open these files

So i still have some confusion on this.